# How to Make XDocument keep new line in attributes like XmlDocument does?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I am using XDocument and LINQ with great ease and comfort, but
one problem arises:

XDocument **removes new lines** inside attribute when you try to output back the xml.
XmlDocument on the other hand, **keeps the new line**.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string res;
    string str = "<element attrib='Some text \n with new line'/>";

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
    res = xDoc.ToString();
    //res dose not containe the new line.

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
    res = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
    //res contains a new line char, that i can replace to something more nice like /r.
    res = res.Replace("&#xA;", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I have a lot of code already written with XDocument, and don't want to rewrite it using XmlDocument. How can I get XDocument to behave like XmlDocument it this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the XML specification attribute value are [normalized](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize) when parsing a document. The normalization replaces all newline character in attribute values with blank characters (`#x20`). Note that this normalization happens already when you create the `XDocument`, not when you write it back to a file and that it is totally conformant to the XML specification.

If you want to retain the newline, you could encode the newline as `&#xA;` in your input:

```
var inputXml = "<element attrib='Some text &#xA; with new line'/>";
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(inputXml);
var attribValue = (string)xDoc.Root.Attribute("attrib");
```